# How to call straight to voice mail?

Tags: android, call, voicemail

I want to create an app that call to the Another users `voice mail inbox` directly from android phone ( Just like [slydial](http://www.slydial.com/) app).
How can i achieve this?   Is this possible via programatically?

Comment: I can't answer fully but in Ireland (and I'm sure other countries) you can access the voicemail direct with a 5 after the network code. So say my number is `123 4567890` then I can just dial `123 5 4567890` that would be an easy implementation, but I don't know about other networks etc. Interestingly they state on the SlyDial site "No, there are some numbers that simply cannot be 'slydialed'. For example, you can not slydial someone who has a prepaid mobile phone, does not have voicemail on his/her phone, their voicemail is full, or if they have a third-party voicemail service."

Comment: Furthermore SlyDial seem to have their own line that diverts the calls to voicemail, I'd imagine inserting a digit into the call would be easier to implement and about as reliable!

Comment: Ross, I can't understand the case of  inserting a digit into the call?

Comment: Ok, well in Ireland if you dial 123 4567890 (as a pretend number obviously) then it calls my phone, if you dial 123 5 4567890 (Inserting the `5`) then it goes straight to my voicemail. So an app would simply take my number and add a 5 in after the network code (123) in this case. If it was international it would be +353 123 5 4567890 to go straight to my voicemail. I think other countries use similar logic, but not all afaik. http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=51873608  EDIT: Doesn't work in the UK at all for example http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=214624

Comment: Thanks ROSSC, I will check that way...

Comment: @RossC I can't find a methode like insert number for us.